# Ms Sql Server Compare Numeric column with string value

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL Server, what is the difference between:

```
select * from Person where Id='7'
```

and

```
select * from Person where Id=7
```

The two queries returns the same results.

The **Id** type is **int**.

should we not compare int to string?

and when should use one of them?

Comment: You should avoid [implicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). And compare directly to `id=7`

Comment: If you want to know what kind of trouble conversions can bring, try the reverse: `where name=3`, with `name` a string column, will give errors when the contents of `name` are converted to `int`, due to the bizarre precedence rules SQL Server has for implicit conversions.

Comment: To add to @JeroenMostert 's comment: [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Although, not sure I agree with the *"bizarre"* statement. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always compare with the same data type and avoid implicit conversions.

```
SELECT 'Not OK!' WHERE 'text' = 1
-- Result: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'text' to data type int.
```

As stated by the data type precedence, when there is a mismatch of the data types, the SQL engine will (in most cases) try to convert the most complex type to the simplest, so comparisons are faster. In this case (`VARCHAR` vs. `INT`), it will always convert the string type to int.

Also, when coding SQL that has implicit conversions with joins and other operations, it's most likely to generate a different execution plan that the one it would with an explicit conversion.

If you have to compare different types, remember to explicitly cast them, not just for the reason mentioned before but it also says to the next developer that the columns or expressions differ in data type.

```
SELECT 'OK!' WHERE 'text' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 1)
```

With some data type you might find unwanted behaviour if you leave implicit conversions.

```
DECLARE @BitValue1 BIT = NULL
DECLARE @BitValue2 BIT = 1

SELECT
    'Oops!'
WHERE
    ISNULL(@BitValue1, -999) = ISNULL(@BitValue2, -999)

-- Result: Oops! (-999 is being converted to bit, which is 1)
```

Comment: You should also mention that improper use of types can affect optimization, such as the use of indexes, table statistics, and partitions.